# How to send json data from Angularjs post to Django view?

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, json, django

I need to send json data using a POST request from Angularjs to my Django view.

I need to get data from database using this json as json format.

I tried some examples using from net resources:

JS Code:

```
$http({
   method: 'POST',
   url: '/mycard/list',
   data:  $.param({test: json})
});
```

Python Code(Django View):

```
def product_list(request):
   if len(request.META['QUERY_STRING']) > 0:
       data = request.body
       data = json.loads(data)
       print data
   else:
       f = open('./mytest.txt','r')
       data = f.read()

   return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json')
```

But it returns 403 error and sometimes it returns 500 error(INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

Answer (score 0):

Service Code

```
var promise = $http({
                      method: 'post',
                      url: '/mycard/list',
                      data:data,
                      contentType:'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                    });
return promise;
```

Python rest api

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def product_list(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            stream = StringIO(request.body)
            data = JSONParser().parse(stream)
        except ValueError:
            return Response(json.dumps(ValueError, default=json_util.default))
        return Response(json.dumps(data, default=json_util.default))
    else:        
        return Response("failure")
```

Answer (score 0):

your json data should be formatted by `JSON.stringify()` like this:

```
$http({
   method: 'POST',
   url: '/mycard/list',
   data:  JSON.stringify({test: json})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- 403 Forbidden maybe because of an invalid CSRF token
- 500 : You might be not posting the data in the format that the backend is expecting. Can you please inspect and see what is the error response it is giving.